# How can I get generated header files into scons dependencies?

Tags: scons

What is the best way to get a generated header file recognized as a dependency for scons? I've been able to do it through a builder when I use python to write the file, but I haven't been able to do it by invoking the script directly. Ideally, in this case, I'd like to have the script run and scons find the "foo.h", which is needed by "hello.c"

I have the following directory structure below. inc/gen.sh will generate an inc/foo.h. I know it generates random number, and this won't get re-generated each time-- we can ignore that for now (I just wanted something to generate a header file).

```
inc
  gen.sh
src
  hello.c
SConstruct
```

hello.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "foo.h"

int main()
{
  printf("My integer is: %d\n", foo);
  return 0;
}
```

inc/gen.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

val=$(echo $((1 + RANDOM % 100)))
echo "int foo = ${val};" > foo.h
```

SConstruct (works, but is probably awful code):

```
import os

def add_target(target, source, env):
  target.append(str(target[0]))
  env.Append(CPPPATH = ['inc'])
  return target, source

def build_function(target, source, env):
  print("I am building {}".format(target[0]))
  with open(str(target[0]), "w") as f:
    # This is not random, and not invoking the gen.sh script. I would rather invoke the gen.sh script
    # here, but whenever I attempt to use an os.system() call, the build fails.
    f.write("int foo = 12345;\n")
  return None

bld = Builder(action = build_function, emitter = add_target)
env = Environment(BUILDERS = {'Foo' : bld})
env.Foo('inc/foo.h', None)

env.Program('hello', ['src/hello.c'])
```

I have also tried this approach, which does not work:

```
env = Environment()

env.Command('inc/foo.h', 'inc/gen.sh', '$SOURCE')
env.Append(CPPPATH = ['inc'])

env.Program('hello', ['src/hello.c'])

env.Depends('hello', 'inc/foo.h')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first SConscript works for me..

```
python ~/devel/scons/git/as_scons/src/script/scons.py
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
build_function(["inc/foo.h", "inc/foo.h"], [])
I am building inc/foo.h
gcc -o src/hello.o -c -Iinc src/hello.c
gcc -o hello src/hello.o
scons: done building targets.
```

I had to make a few changes for the second one to work:

SConstruct

```
env = Environment()

env.Command('inc/foo.h', 'inc/gen.sh', './$SOURCE $TARGET')
env.Append(CPPPATH = ['inc'])

env.Program('hello', ['src/hello.c'])

# env.Depends('hello', 'inc/foo.h')
```

gen.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
val=$(echo $((1 + RANDOM % 100)))
echo "int foo = ${val};" > $1
```

That yields:

```
python ~/devel/scons/git/as_scons/src/script/scons.py -f SConstruct.2
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
./inc/gen.sh inc/foo.h
gcc -o src/hello.o -c -Iinc src/hello.c
gcc -o hello src/hello.o
scons: done building targets.
```

Comment: Thanks! Is the $TARGET in the command necessary? That's just getting passed to the command line, right?

Also, are env.Command() functions guaranteed to happen before compilation? My concern here is that in a larger codebase if I run multithreaded with a -j# option, scons will try to compile the source files (ie: hello.c) and not have the generated header files in place yet. I want to make sure scons knows the source files depend on having the header files generated.

Comment: SCons knows about targets which aren't yet build and will figure out that the source file needs a generated header file and do the right thing.